# How to legally jailbreak an iPhone?

Tags: legal, ios, iphone

I'm looking to jailbreak my work phone to pen test iOS applications. From a compliance point of view I've got the green light as long as I don't go on our companies intranet with it or put company data on there.

However it appears I'll be breaking apple's end user agreement. I'd like to jailbreak this phone but I want to do it right and have my back appropriately covered from a legal stand point. What do professional iOS pen testers do to jailbreak their test devices without breaking end-user license?

From the apple's website:

> Apple strongly cautions against installing any software that hacks
>   iOS. It is also important to note that unauthorized modification of
>   iOS is a violation of the iOS end-user software license agreement and
>   because of this, Apple may deny service for an iPhone, iPad, or iPod
>   touch that has installed any unauthorized software.

Comment: What part of " unauthorized modification of iOS is a violation of the iOS end-user software license agreement" don't you understand? If you agreed to this then there is no legal way apart from getting an authorized version from Apple. And Apple does not provide an authorized jailbreaked version.

Comment: As far as legal advice goes: At least in Germany (and I suspect that to be true in the UK as well, where your profile says you are located) if the device is yours or you have permission from the owner, you will not get prosecuted as far as the legal tag goes. However, as you already know, there might be problems not regarding law enforcement but Apple itself which might lead to binding legal problems that are not law enforcement.

Comment: I agree with @SmokeDispenser that local laws might consider part of this agreement invalid or not enforceable (which is not the same as legal). But details about this are not related to information security and therefore off topic here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It does look pretty cut and dry which is why I'm asking. iOS apps are no different to any other software eco system where pen testing is a vital layer of security. I'm just confused how it's a booming profession yet every pen tester is breaking legally binding agreements. Hence I'm asking if anyone experienced in this area know how they proceed with this legally.

Comment: Several countries have exceptions for specific use cases like [this one](http://www.macworld.com/article/1152935/jailbreak_exemption.html) but again: legal advice is off topic here.

Comment: I do think it's relevant, people looking to jailbreak their iPhone for pen testing are going to come here for advise on how to safely do it rather than a law forum. There will be users of this site with experience of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, they accept that Apple won't service the device if it gets damaged, and that future releases of iOS may not work on it. There may also be issues with jail-break detection in apps being tested, preventing them from working. Ideally, you would have multiple devices, some jail-broken, others not, and then use the minimal amount of difference from stock to test - if you can test by intercepting traffic from a stock device (it's a built in feature), do that for those functions, and only move onto using rooted devices for more intrusive testing, noting any discrepancies between the devices behaviour.